# Nodejs CSV data export system for users

Tags: node.js, csv

I need to allow users to export their data in csv format. I have written app in nodejs. The export data for users can be huge. So i was wondering How to handle such situation in nodejs. Should i user process.nexttick or child process api of nodejs? Also are there any good module available for nodejs to convert data from mysql to csv.

Comment: what is meant by data is huge? are you running a webapplication which should export that data on request? one thing i can tell you for sure is that you shouldnt use process.nextTick. use streams (stream from db into your csv generator to your client)

Comment: I mean data could be huge say 10-20 MB or more

Comment: and you need to create the csv realtime?

Comment: NO actually i can email users after the process is complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read line by line from your mysql-db, and append line by line to your file

i dont know that much about the mysqlmodule, so i'm assuming here each line is just an array, therefore the 'row.join(';')'. if thats not the case (maybe its an object), you should fix that.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var connection = require('mysql').createConnection({yourdbsettingshere});

function processRow (row) {
  fs.appendFile('your-file.csv', row.join(';'), function (err) {
    connection.resume();
  });
}

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM WHATEVER');

query
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // do something when an error happens
  })
 .on('fields', function(fields) {
   processRow(fields);
 })
 .on('result', function(row) {
   // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
   connection.pause();
   processRow(row, function (err) {
     connection.resume();
   });
 })
 .on('end', function() {
    // now you can mail your user
 });
```

if you have a lot of requests, you could use the [compute-cluster](https://npmjs.org/package/compute-cluster) module for distributing your workload

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying it out now. do you think we can utilize https://github.com/koles/ya-csv this module aswell?

Comment: Also i wanted to ask if i should do this process in processs.nexttick? or child process?

Comment: read the last line of my answer! compute-cluster uses childprocesses. if you stay in the same process you could use process.nextTick for every new csv-generation-start

Comment: Will this write to file on every row?

Comment: my example code? yes! read what fs.appendFile does here: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: so if i say i have 100 rows. it will write to the file 100 times. Will there be any performance issues?

Comment: it could be, but that depends how many files will be generated per second/minute. if it's a lot, you should use real stream objects (the mysql module has some short explanation on how to do so) and stream to the file via fs.createWriteStream. node.js is blazing fast, but it's all a matter of workload to be done...

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right way. I will study more on crete write stream. Also the returned row is object and not array.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not working because CSV files are separated by `,` not `;`. Also there is no newline character `\n` after the end of each row and the `fields` object contains information about the `column attributes` not the `data rows`. `results` contains the rows resulted from query. Hence I wrote my own code for generating CSV files. If you need more explanation then please comment, I will provide.

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM category', function (error, results, fields) {
 var reportFile = Date.now();
 fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(__dirname + '/../reports/' + reportFile + '.csv', 'w'));
 var attributes = [];
 var row = [];
 for(var x = 0; x<fields.length; x++) attributes.push(fields[x].name);
 fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/../reports/' + reportFile + '.csv', attributes.join(','), function (err) {
    if(err) console.log('Error appending fields', err);
    fs.appendFileSync(__dirname + '/../reports/' + reportFile + '.csv', '\n');
    for(var x = 0; x<results.length; x++) {
        row = [];
        for(var y = 0; y<attributes.length; y++){
            row.push(results[x][attributes[y]]);
        }
        fs.appendFileSync(__dirname + '/../reports/' + reportFile + '.csv', row.join(','));
        fs.appendFileSync(__dirname + '/../reports/' + reportFile + '.csv', '\n');
    }
    req.reportFile = reportFile;
    next();
 });
});
```