# NODEjs - write data from mysql to file

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am currently trying to use node and so far it is good,
but my problem is I query the database and i get the result back.
but when i try to write file i get errors,

I have tried this way

```
fs.writeFile('table.txt', rows, 
              function (err) {
                   if (err) throw err;
                   console.log('Saved!');
});
```

and another way

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("my_file.txt");
 stream.once('open', function(fd) {
     for (var i = 0;i < rows.length; i++) {
           stream.write('test: ', rows[i].i);
      }

      stream.write("My first row\n");
      stream.write("My second row\n");
      stream.end();
  });
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong, i have spend a few hours now looking 
any suggestions or Idea's

thanks in advance

Comment: Check for permissions. what error you are getting?

Comment: permission is fine, i am getting the data, it's just error when writing to file, If i did it the first way i get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] and if i did the 2nd way i get  TypeError: Unknown encoding: 
    at Buffer.write (buffer.js:441:13)

Comment: Try this, might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188337/nodejs-csv-data-export-system-for-users

Comment: Thanks I will give thank link a try,

Comment: Aren't the data you gather from your request gives some binary data ?

What does it do if you try to output to console your lines ?

Comment: when i use the console.log, it output the values, that is why i am a bit confuse on why it would not insert into the file,

Answer (score 0):

The first writing method should do fine.

Aren't you trying to write the array element when writing it ?

try

```
fs.writeFile('table.txt', rows.join('\n'), function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Saved!');
});
```

If that does not work, write the output of rows.

```
console.log(typeof(rows))
```

Concerning your second writing method, The second 'i' is in your line seems to be a typo which may lead to unexpected results.

```
stream.write('test: ', rows[i].i)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply i will give your code a try, it does make sense but i have also tried another way, which works, what i did was put the result in a variable

Comment: and then add it example:                                                          var fite = '';   

for (var i in rows) { fite += rows[i].Curr + '\t' }

fs.writeFile( 'C:test.txt', fite, function (err) {
                                    if (err) throw err;
                                    console.log('Saved!');
                                });  

but i am going to give ur code a try as well, as it is good to know different ways. thank you again

Comment: You can add your own answer if you found out what works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get it, to write to file, when i get the SQL result, i loop through it appending it to a variable and then i write to file here is a example

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM Table', 
     function(err, rows, fields){ if(err)   {
         throw err;
     }else{

       var fite = '';
       for (var i in rows) {
          fite += rows[i].field1 + '\t';
          fite += rows[i].field2 + '\n';
       }

       fs.writeFile( 'C:\\folder\\test.txt', fite, function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                         console.log('Saved!');
                    });


    }
```

I would like to thank those u have helped me and gave me other methods to try 
thank you very much